# cm - illegal unit of measure in tabular?

Tags: tables, errors, tabularx

I wanted to created a table and I get an illegal unit of measure error, but I use cm, which works great normally.... I don't know why but sometimes I get this error and sometimes it works great...
[image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\title{Stundenplanung Selbstverteidigung}
\date{}
\maketitle

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1}}

\begin{tabular}{L{4cm}L{4cm}L{3cm}}
Name & Material & Anleitung \\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add a `#` in every of your `\newcolumntype` definitions:

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

`\newcolumntype` defines a macro with one argument, this argument(the column width) can be accessed by `#1`.

Answer (score 8):

You have

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1}}
```

You meant

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

as it is it always uses `1` as the width and complains about no unit.